# Using multiple criteria in subset function and logical operators

Tags: r, subset, logical-operators, operator-precedence

If I want to select a subset of data in R, I can use the subset function. I wanted to base an analysis on data that that was matching one of a few criteria, e.g. that a certain variable was either 1, 2 or 3. 
I tried

```
myNewDataFrame <- subset(bigfive, subset = (bigfive$bf11==(1||2||3)))
```

It did always just select values that matched the first of the criteria, here 1. My assumption was that it would start with 1 and if it does evaluate to "false" it would go on to 2 and than to 3, and if none matches the statement after == is "false" and if one of them matches, it is "true".

I got the right result using

```
 newDataFrame <- subset(bigfive, subset = (bigfive$bf11==c(1,2,3)))
```

But I would like to be able to select data via logical operators, so: why did the first approach not work?

Comment: Take a look at the ?Logic help page. the `||` form operates left to right and only examines the first element in the vector. `%in%` would also be a helpful operator to use in these situations. an SO search for `[r] %in%` should be enlightening.

Comment: @Chase `||` and `|` are useless here: `1||2||3` and `1|2|3` evaluate to TRUE so the subset would only include those where `bf11` was TRUE (or something that evaluated to TRUE). `%in%` is more than helpful here.

Comment: @Gavin - thanks for finishing my sentence there - had to run to another meeting.

Comment: What you say "got the right result" probably misses several cases where bf11 is indeed 1, 2 or 3. `%in%` works best, as Gavin Simpson says

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The correct operator is `%in%` here. Here is an example with dummy data:

```
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(bf11 = sample(4, 10, replace = TRUE),
                  foo = runif(10))
```

giving:

```
> head(dat)
  bf11       foo
1    2 0.2059746
2    2 0.1765568
3    3 0.6870228
4    4 0.3841037
5    1 0.7698414
6    4 0.4976992
```

The subset of `dat` where `bf11` equals any of the set `1,2,3` is taken as follows using `%in%`:

```
> subset(dat, subset = bf11 %in% c(1,2,3))
   bf11       foo
1     2 0.2059746
2     2 0.1765568
3     3 0.6870228
5     1 0.7698414
8     3 0.9919061
9     3 0.3800352
10    1 0.7774452
```

As to why your original didn't work, break it down to see the problem. Look at what `1||2||3` evaluates to:

```
> 1 || 2 || 3
[1] TRUE
```

and you'd get the same using `|` instead. As a result, the `subset()` call would only return rows where `bf11` was `TRUE` (or something that evaluated to `TRUE`).

What you could have written would have been something like:

```
subset(dat, subset = bf11 == 1 | bf11 == 2 | bf11 == 3)
```

Which gives the same result as my earlier `subset()` call. The point is that you need a series of single comparisons, not a comparison of a series of options. But as you can see, `%in%` is far more useful and less verbose in such circumstances. Notice also that I have to use `|` as I want to compare each element of `bf11` against `1`, `2`, and `3`, in turn. Compare:

```
> with(dat, bf11 == 1 || bf11 == 2)
[1] TRUE
> with(dat, bf11 == 1 | bf11 == 2)
 [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: How can I find help page about "%in%"?  I used ?%in% but it didn't work.

Comment: @kostia Quote the operator: something like `?"%in%"`

Answer (score 12):

For your example, I believe the following should work:

```
myNewDataFrame <- subset(bigfive, subset = bf11 == 1 | bf11 == 2 | bf11 == 3)
```

See the examples in `?subset` for more.  Just to demonstrate, a more complicated logical subset would be:

```
data(airquality)
dat <- subset(airquality, subset = (Temp > 80 & Month > 5) | Ozone < 40)
```

And as Chase points out, `%in%` would be more efficient in your example:

```
myNewDataFrame <- subset(bigfive, subset = bf11 %in% c(1, 2, 3))
```

As Chase also points out, make sure you understand the difference between `|` and `||`.  To see help pages for operators, use `?'||'`, where the operator is quoted.

Comment: `?'||'` works fine in R, as does `?"||"`. The point is that these operators and some other constructs need to be _quoted_. Hence my removal of the sentences from your Answer.