# How to subset data in R: participant only needs to meet one of five criteria?

Tags: r, conditional-statements, subset

I'm having a lot of trouble figuring out how to subset a data set in R despite reading through many pages here. The set contains information from over 3000 participants. Each participant was asked about five different health conditions and gave binary answers (i.e., yes/no diabetes; yes/no obesity, etc.). How do I make a subset that includes people who have only ONE of the conditions? For instance, everyone in this new subset would have either obesity or diabetes or high cholesterol, but none would have two or more conditions.

Thank you!!

ETA: After a night's sleep, I looked at everything (and the comments) again. Here's some clarification and what I've done since.

Sample data (mydata) (0 = no, 1 = yes)

```
Participant  HighCho  Diabetes  Obesity
1              1        1        0
2              0        1        1
3              1        0        0
4              0        0        0
5              0        1        0
```

I want my subset outcome to include only those with none of the three conditions or only one of the three:

```
Participant  HighCho  Diabetes  Obesity 
3             1        0        0
4             0        0        0
5             0        1        0
```

I've written:

```
new.data <- subset(mydata = (HighCho == 0 & Diabetes == 0 & Obesity==0) | HighCho == 1 | Diabetes == 1 | Obesity == 1)
```

My problem is that even though I capture everyone who is free from all conditions, I still include people who have more than one condition. I thought with my "or" statement, I would only include those with only one of the three conditions (rather than two). Any insights as to what I might be doing incorrectly?

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and expected output based on that.  If you need to separate each subset, check `?split`.  ie. `split(yourdata, list(yourdata$grp1, yourdata$grp2), drop=TRUE)`

Comment: I get 40 hits on an SO search: `[r] subset multiple conditions`

Comment: You will need the OR operator (`|`). Something along the lines of answer from Gavin: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794414/using-multiple-criteria-in-subset-function-and-logical-operators-in-r

Comment: I've edited the original question to be more clear and to reflect what I have done. Thank you all for all the insights so far. Still having trouble despite reading many answers re: subsetting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `apply` function to `sum` the number of conditions each participant has.

`mydata[apply(mydata[, c('HighCho', 'Diabetes', 'Obesity')], 1, sum) %in% 0:1, ]`