# How to filter based on a specific criteria in R

Tags: r

I have the mpg dataset from r and I'm trying to filter based on a specific criteria.
I'm trying to filter the manufacturer that is "Toyota" or "Ford" and the class of the car is "midsize". How would I do this?

this is what I have so far

```
-mpg[(mpg$manufacturer == "toyota" | mpg$manufacturer == "volkswagen"), ]
```

Here is what the data looks like

[image]

Comment: `%in%` is what you are looking for i think - `mpg[mpg$manufacturer %in% c("toyota","ford") & mpg$class == "midsize",]` , which means this is possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794414/using-multiple-criteria-in-subset-function-and-logical-operators

Answer (score 0):

You can use **grep** for that:

```
mpg[ intersect( grep("toyota|volkswagen",mpg$manufacturer),
 grep("midsize",mpg$class) ), ]

# A tibble: 14 x 11
   manufacturer model  displ  year   cyl trans    drv     cty   hwy fl    class 
   <chr>        <chr>  <dbl> <int> <int> <chr>    <chr> <int> <int> <chr> <chr> 
 1 toyota       camry    2.2  1999     4 manual(… f        21    29 r     midsi…
 2 toyota       camry    2.2  1999     4 auto(l4) f        21    27 r     midsi…
 3 toyota       camry    2.4  2008     4 manual(… f        21    31 r     midsi…
 4 toyota       camry    2.4  2008     4 auto(l5) f        21    31 r     midsi…
 5 toyota       camry    3    1999     6 auto(l4) f        18    26 r     midsi…
 6 toyota       camry    3    1999     6 manual(… f        18    26 r     midsi…
 7 toyota       camry    3.5  2008     6 auto(s6) f        19    28 r     midsi…
 8 volkswagen   passat   1.8  1999     4 manual(… f        21    29 p     midsi…
 9 volkswagen   passat   1.8  1999     4 auto(l5) f        18    29 p     midsi…
10 volkswagen   passat   2    2008     4 auto(s6) f        19    28 p     midsi…
11 volkswagen   passat   2    2008     4 manual(… f        21    29 p     midsi…
12 volkswagen   passat   2.8  1999     6 auto(l5) f        16    26 p     midsi…
13 volkswagen   passat   2.8  1999     6 manual(… f        18    26 p     midsi…
14 volkswagen   passat   3.6  2008     6 auto(s6) f        17    26 p     midsi…
```